# simulate Boolean Model with R

Tags: process, model, boolean, point, spatstat

I am complete Newbie on programming with R, especially with the library spatstat. And so i hope that anyone can help me.

I want to simulate a Boolean Model. In my case, this is a Poisson-Pointprocess with closed circles with radius r around the points of the point process.

With X = rpoispp (100) I can already simulate the point process. But I have no idea how to generate the circles around the dots.

my google research was unfortunately not successful.

Thanks for help, 
Perry

Comment: Please consider upvoting and/or accepting an answer if it solves your problem or explain what an answer is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Googleing 'Boolean model spatstat' gave me
[this helpfile](https://rdrr.io/cran/spatstat/man/laslett.html) as one of the
first hits. In the examples section there is an example of a Boolean model
in the unit square with disc radius 0.2:

```r
library(spatstat)
X <- discs(runifpoint(15) %mark% 0.2, npoly=16)
plot(X, main = "", col = "gray")
```

[image]

Is this what you need?

Above `X` is a polygonal approximation of the union of discs. Alternatively
the Boolean model is often represented simply as a marked point
pattern with the disc radius as the mark. What is more convenient depends on
the context.

FYI: There are several equivalent ways of attaching a (vector) of marks `m`
to a point pattern `X`: `marks(X) <- m` and `X %mark% m`.
<sup>Created on 2018-11-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your This is not exactly what I need. I prefer the "dot-marking" method, but have problems here as well. I create point pattern with disc radius like this. X=rpoisspp(100) and m=0.5 for my radius and than marks(X)=m.  But it makes no distinction what value I use for m, my plot does not change.

Comment: You have to consult the help file for `plot.ppp`. There is an argument called `mark.scale` or something like that you can use to set the plotted circles to the physical size. Note that circles of radius/diameter 0.5 will be very big in the default window which is the unit square...

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a marked point pattern and use the correct value of `markscale`
when plotting with `plot.ppp`:

```r
library(spatstat)
X <- ppp(0.5, 0.5, window = owin()) # Single point in middle of unit square
marks(X) <- 0.5 
plot.ppp(X, markscale = 1, legend = FALSE) # Mark interpreted directly as diameter of cirle
```

[image]

```r
plot.ppp(X, markscale = 2, legend = FALSE) # 2*mark interpreted as diameter of cirle (i.e. mark = radius)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much. I now have what I need.
I still have a question, but I do not know if that's even possible.

I am interested in the question of "how much of my observation window is covered" (in %). 

Do you know if I can solve such a problem in R?

Comment: Use `area(discs(X, radii = marks(X)))/area(Window(X))`, where X is your marked point pattern.

Answer (score -1):

Now, After a little self-study I came to the following results:

```
> X=rpoispp(8) 
> m=1
> marks(X)=m
> plot(X)
```

i get this picture:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA39U.jpg)

Now, i want to scale the Radii of the marks. I do not understand how R sets the radii of the circles. I found this on a tutorial site: "If markscale is given, then a mark value of m is plotted as a circle of radius m * markscale (if m is positive)". I tested it and was surprised by the result. If I understood correctly, the radius of the markers would have to stay the same with

```
>plot(X, markscale = 1)
```

and would have to double by

```
>plot(X, markscale = 2)
```

but it does not.

PS: Sorry for my bad english.

Perry

Comment: Please show plots to show the problem. When I load `spatstat` and run `plot(spruces, markscale = 1); plot(spruces, markscale = 2, col = 2, add = TRUE)` it looks like the diameters of the circles are doubled.

Comment: Hey Ege Rubak, sorry for my late answer. You are right. The problem was that my screen resolution was affecting the scaling. Thank you for your help.

Comment: OK. Good to know that there isn't a bug to track down. Again: Please consider upvoting/accepting an answer to show that the issue has been resolved.

Comment: I do. But i got this message: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Comment: Ok. Don't worry about that then. Anyway, if you click the check mark by an answer it becomes green and the question no longer appears as unanswered.